# sendmail does not recognize the local host name

Tags: linux, centos, dovecot, sendmail

Recently I'm learning Sendmail in CentOS,But I have got some prombles when I am following the tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=).
I have followed the steps in the video, but when I try to test the Sendmail with the mail command,Sendmail Response that:

```
example.com: Name server timeout
user@example.com... Transient parse error -- message queued for future delivery
user@example.com... queued
```

---

It seems that sendmail must have an MX record to deliver mail to the local virtual domain, which is not mentioned in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case,MX record is required.